# How do I see if a cell contains any word from a separate list, and then return a value from lookup?

Tags: excel-formula, string-matching, substitution

I have a list of product names and then a list of confirmed trademarks (on a separate tab) that need to be applied for different countries. I want it to append/substitute the appropriate trademark to the product name, but still keep the rest of the product name.

I've made a sample sheet here to see how mine is set up and the desired output: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jroqaBlfKFGSZhmwZvixd9CkA-fBHO1lQJE9nbGHkIg/edit?usp=sharing

I started a formula that helps match the terms (in column G), but now I can't figure out how to get it to match country THEN output the appropriate trademark substitution.

See description above.

Comment: `=IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(A2,LEFT(A2,SEARCH(" ",A2)-1),INDEX(Trademarks!$C$2:$C$5,MATCH(LEFT(A2,SEARCH(" ",A2)-1)&B2,Trademarks!$A$2:$A$5&Trademarks!$B$2:$B$5,0))),A2)` as an [array formula](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula) if you have legacy Excel, or as is if you're using Google Sheets (since you _were_ trying to solve with a Google-only formula)